# I am getting error when testing from Postman : HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

When I deploy my WebAPI Project on IIS-8 and test is using Postman it gives me error " HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized
You are not authorized to view this page due to invalid authentication headers.

More Information:
This error occurs when the WWW-Authenticate header sent to the Web server is not supported by the server configuration. Check the authentication method for the resource, and verify which authentication method the client used. The error occurs when the authentication methods are different. To determine which type of authentication the client is using, check the authentication settings for the client."

Locally it works fine.

My Web.Config content is:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="WhiteListedIPAddresses"  value="::1,192.168.9.175,192.168.9.234"/> <!-- Example "::1,192.168.9.234" -->
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>

  <!--<authentication mode="Windows" /> -->

    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>

  </system.webServer>
  <connectionStrings>
  <!--<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=ASAProv.80; Trusted_Connection=True;Data Source=softwrench;Persist Security Info=True;commlinks=TCPIP;" /> -->
  <add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="Provider=ASAProv.80; Trusted_Connection=True;Data Source=Corporate;Persist Security Info=True;commlinks=TCPIP;" />
</connectionStrings>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Basic Authentication code:

```
namespace WebApiSampleProject
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            string sql;

            OleDbConnection conn;
            OleDbDataReader rdr;
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            var authHeader = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization;

            if (authHeader != null)
            {
                var authenticationToken = actionContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter;
                var decodedAuthenticationToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(authenticationToken));
                var usernamePasswordArray = decodedAuthenticationToken.Split(':');
                var userName = usernamePasswordArray[0];
                var password = usernamePasswordArray[1];


                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
                conn.Open();

                sql = "SELECT ucode, upassword FROM user_list where ucode = ?";
                cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn);
                OleDbParameter usercode = cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar, 15);
                usercode.Value = userName;

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                var userid = "";
                var passcode = ""; 

                if (rdr.HasRows)
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {                             

                        userid = rdr["ucode"].ToString();

                        passcode = rdr["upassword"].ToString();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }


                rdr.Close();
                conn.Close();

                var isValid = userName == userid && password == passcode;

                //------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                if (isValid)
                {
                    var principal = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(userName), null);
                    Thread.CurrentPrincipal = principal;

                    //actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,"User " + userName + " successfully authenticated");

                    return;
                }
            }

            HandleUnathorized(actionContext);
        }

        private static void HandleUnathorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            //var host = actionContext.Request.RequestUri.DnsSafeHost;
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Username or Password is Incorrect" );

            actionContext.Response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic Scheme='Data' location = 'http://192.168.9.234:");

        }



    }
}
```

Basic Authentication Registered in Webapiconfig as:

```
config.Filters.Add(new BasicAuthenticationAttribute());
```

Using Postman client I passed Username and Password under Basic Auth alongwith the Json Request body.

Comment: You are using an authorization header attribute for authentication for your `BasicAuthenticationAttribute` . Authentication and Authorization are two different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have set

```
<section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
```

to

```
<section name="authorization" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

in applicationHost.Config file, to fix the issue.